# Custom item states for android selectors

Tags: android, coding-style, selector, heatmap

I see examples of selectors using android states like 'selected' to define style.  Here a simplified example:

```
<selector>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_normal" />
</selector>
```

So, my question is: Can I define and use my own state instead of

```
android:state_selected="true"
```

My goal is to color shapes based on an integer value, like simple version of this heatmap:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look onto [LevelList](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList) and [LevelListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html), it looks like the drawable is what you need.

Answer (score 5):

What you originally wanted can be done with custom boolean attributes.

You can see a coded example [here](http://www.charlesharley.com/2012/programming/custom-drawable-states-in-android/)